# Interpolation (akima) omits part of data when x/y contains duplicate elements

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, interpolation

I am making a function which receives three vectors, interpolates them using *akima* and plots them using plot_ly(). Although the general code works, I am encountering issues with scaling of the z-matrix that *interp()* outputs.

Let me give you an example:

- x is a non-NA numeric containing some duplicate values.
- y is a non-NA numeric containing some duplicate values.
- z is a non-NA continuous vector

Some summary statistics:

```
> unique(x)
[1] 60 48 36 32 18 24 30 15 12 28 21 19 54 20 16 27 10 39 14 17  9  6 50  8 13
> range(x)
[1]  6 60

> unique(y)
[1] 10.00 10.50 13.50 12.50 14.00 12.00 11.00  9.00 11.50  9.25 13.00 10.25 6.50 6.75 8.25 9.50
[17]  8.00 8.85  9.75  7.90  7.00  8.60  8.75  7.50  8.90  8.50  7.49  7.40  5.50  7.60  7.25  8.35
[33]  6.00  5.00  7.75  7.35  6.30  4.50  5.75  8.40  5.60  5.90  7.74  9.90  6.20  5.80
> range(y)
[1]  4.5 14.0


> head(z)
[1] 2.877272 3.267328 3.175478 3.843326 4.809792 2.827825
> range(z)
[1]  2.316529 28.147808
```

I implement the baseline function below:

```
labs = list(x = 'x', y = 'y', z = 'z')

mat = interp(x, y, z, duplicate = 'mean', extrap = T, xo = sort(unique(x)))

plot_ly(x = mat$x, y = mat$y, z = mat$z, type = 'surface') %>%
    layout(title = title,
           scene = list(xaxis = list(title = labs$x),
                        yaxis = list(title = labs$y),
                        zaxis = list(title = labs$z)))
```

When I run this, the output is the following:

[image: Plot 1]

The issue is that a portion of the data is not covered in this picture. For instance, there is a sizeable data portion around x > 50, y < 11 that is omitted by the interpolation (and hence not plotted).

```
length(x[x > 50])
[1] 304
> length(y[x > 50 & y < 11])
[1] 290
> length(z[x > 50 & y < 11])
[1] 290
```

I suspected that this has to do with the duplicate x values. Hence, I configured the xo argument in *interp()* such that:

```
mat = interp(x, y, z, duplicate = 'mean', xo = sort(unique(x)), decreasing = T)
```

In which case the previously omitted region is partially plotted. It looks like the following:

[image: fig2]

Nonetheless, the x and y axes still do not correspond to their respective data ranges (despite data availability). Bottom line: How do I tweak the function such that the surface always extends the full range of x and y?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the error arose from *plot_ly()*. Apparently, the z-matrix cannot be passed straight through from *interp()* to *plot_ly()*, as the axis become erroneously passed through to the graph. Hence, the interpolated z-matrix needs to be transformed.

If you use these two functions in combination, ensure to carry out the transformation of z as shown below:

```
mat = interp(x,y,z, duplicate = 'mean')

x = mat$x
y = mat$y
z = matrix(mat$z, nrow = length(mat$y), byrow = TRUE)

plot_ly(x, y ,z, type = 'surface')
```